# how to hide text in an html textbox

Tags: javascript, html

i am having a simple html text box what i want just as the user type something in it the text should be invisible but the text should be there

```
<html>
<head>
<title>My Page</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hide()
{
document.forms["text"].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<form name="myform">
<div align="center">
<input type="text" size="25" onkeyup="return hide();">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i have written the code what iam doing in the code block but it is not showing

Comment: Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @chase can i ask why? iam having a name field and password field i just want to hide the password text

Comment: set the type of the field to password <input type="password" />,  The way you're suggesting maintains visibility to the code, just not to the eyes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mac,

What you're doing is kind-of impossible to accomplish using straightforward means. When you use the code you've included in the question, you're actually removing the visibility of the entire box, not just the text content.

Some ideas:

1. Make the textcolor the same as the background color.
2. Use the onKeyPress event, after every keystroke take the value from this box, and append it into a hidden textbox you've got elsewhere on the page (or a javascript variable.

Combining these should be pretty effective in what you're tryin to do.

More important is the question: Why would you want to do this? Could you elaborate on what it is you're trying to accomplish here?

Edit: I see you're doing this for passwords. In that case, why not use the <input type="password"> field? That way the browser know it's a password field and hides the input automatically (using the standard dots, or stars).

Comment: nothing just experimenting something got stuck in this issue actually i look this behavior in MySql while logging through command prompt no specific reason 
anyways thanks kander

Answer (score 2):

instead of setting `visibility="hidden"` try `display="none"`

Edit: didn't noticed it's about passwords - in this case you should use `type=password` for the input element.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're trying to make a homebrew password field? It would be much simpler to just use `<input type="password" ...>` instead.

Comment: except these are now autofilled, sometimes that isn't desired.

Answer (score 1):

For a Password protected field please just use the "password" type.

```
<input type="password" size="25" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give color property as trasparent to the element i.e. to the Input in your case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).